# How can i use TypeORM with better-sqlite3

Tags: typeorm, better-sqlite3

How can i use TypeORM with better-sqlite3?

on the official [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/better-sqlite3-connection-options), there is a section form better-sqlite3.

I already installed by `typeorm@latest` and `typeorm@next` but there is no options for better-sqlite3 yet.

If i try to force initialize it, i got the following error

> MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "better-sqlite3" given. Supported drivers are: "cordova", "expo", "mariadb", "mongodb", "mssql", "mysql", "oracle", "postgres", "sqlite", "sqljs", "react-native", "aurora-data-api", "aurora-data-api-pg".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have to install https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3 --- with npm: `npm install better-sqlite3`

Answer (score 7):

The `better-sqlite3` driver was added in `typeorm@0.2.26`.

1. Export your existing database.
2. Update `typeorm` to `0.2.26` or higher.
3. Install the package `better-sqlite3`. `sqlite3` can be uninstalled.
4. In your `ormconfig.json` change the type to `"type": "better-sqlite3",`
5. Import the database exported in step 1.

Comment: Correct answer!